# Should we avoid the size definition inside the xml?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-resources, android-screen-support

Is there any reason to avoid having `dp`s defined directly in the xml files?
E.g. is there any reason to prefer:

```
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/left_margin"
```

over this:

```
android:layout_marginLeft=16dp
```

If I understand correctly, this would make sense only for tablets but in that case won't we have a relevant xml in `land` with the relevant values?
Also if is there anything to be careful in regards to adding something to `dimen.xml`? E.g. should `left_margin` be defined in all `dimen.xml` for all dimension?

Comment: If `left_margin` is met more than 2 times it should go to `dimen.xml`, otherwise `16dp` is fine.

Comment: @Onik: Is set more than 2 times where? I didn't understand

Comment: Sorry for describing it briefly. I meant if it's met more than twice in one or (moreover) several `xml` layout files. Why modifying the value in multiple files instead of one (`dimen.xml`)?!

Answer (score 2):

There's a good reason for using the first.  Lets say that you decide on really big devices you want a bigger margin.  With the first, you only have to override the dimens file and override the 1 dimension.  In the second, you have to override the entire layout, which causes larger maintenance issues.

(Also you should almost always be using marginStart and marginEnd instead of left and right, so you handle RTL languages correctly).

Comment: For the really big devices, would I need a second `dimens.xml` in a specific directory? What happens if that is missing?

Comment: Then it would fall back to the default dimens file.  This is about being able to customize for different conditions with the minimum effort.

Answer (score 1):

One good reason would be that maybe you have a whole lot of layouts where `marginLeft` needs to be the same. You could set them all to `16dp` right in the layout files, but what if you need to change that dimension? If you have `16dp` defined in every layout, you'll have to change every single instance of it, and you might forget some. If it's defined in `dimens` you only have to change it once.

Another reason would be themers. Someone might make a theme for your app. It's a lot easier to override extracted values than having to override and copy an entire layout just to change one value.

And as Gabe says, you really should use `start` and `end` instead of `left` and `right`,  whenever possible. Otherwise, your app will look terrible on devices using RTL.

Comment: So `start` and `end` is for `LinearLayout` too?

Comment: Any time you could use `start` or `end` in place of `left` or `right` you should. It doesn't only apply to margins, but also padding, relations, gravity, etc.

Comment: I get the point about instead of changing it in every layout file, change it once, but then what is the convention to use as a name? I can't name it e.g. `<dimen name="left_margin">16dp</dimen>` or `screen_left_margin` or `left_margin_16`. So this is confusing to me

Comment: You can name it whatever you want. I usually go for something descriptive, so I know what it's for.

Comment: If it is meant to be reused across multiple layout files (=views) if a reference to a specific view is mentioned in then name then it seems wrong. If I name it `left_margin_16` then I can't just change from `16dp` to e.g. `22dp` and have the `_16` in the name. Also the `left_margin` is too generic. What if another `left_margin` of `22dp` was needed? Do I make sense?

Comment: You could use something like `app_icon_left_margin` if you maybe had a few different layouts where there's an application icon on the left. Or, you could say `left_margin_default` if you want to use standard margins across the whole app.